# Proving that $W^{\perp}$ s isomorphic to $V/W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$. Prove that $W^{\perp}$ is isomorphic to $V/W$.

I'm thinking first isomorphism theorem but what surjective homorphism can I choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\forall x\in V: x=u+v$ where $u\in W$ and $v\in W^{\perp}$ and $u,v$ is unique (proven in many classical text book)

Then you may choose $f(x)=v$. Then $\operatorname{Im}f=W^{\perp}$ and $\operatorname{Ker}f=W$ and first isomorphism theorem gives us...